# MongoDB - Crear rol para permisos a coleccion

Tags: mongodb

Estoy ejecutando el siguiente codigo para crear un rol de permisos a una coleccion en especifico:

```
db.createRole({role:'emr_user_role',privileges:[{resource:{db:'tickets', collection: 'emr_interface'}, actions: ['find','remove','insert','update']}], roles: []});
.
```

Luego, creo el usuario bajo dicho rol creado:

```
db.createUser({user: 'emr',pwd: 'MDCloudPS',roles: [{role: "emr_user_role", db: "tickets"}]})
.
```

Tanto el Rol como el Usuario se crean correctamente, el problema es que a pesar de que al rol le asigno acciones de find, insert, remove, y update, únicamente puedo ver la información, como si se tratara de sólo lectura.

Para crear el Rol y el Usuario me ubico en la base de datos "tickets" (use tickets).

En qué estoy fallando?

Comment: estás creando el rol y el usuario en la base admin?

Comment: No, no estoy en Admin.